# Clarify vpn behaviour

Tags: wireless-networking, vpn

I have a common and probably stupid question regarding vpn behaviour, but still it would be good to confirm my understanding. If i share internet from let's say my mobile phone (via Wi-Fi hotspot) and some other machine uses it (as Wi-Fi network) and then, this machine establishes vpn to some other network, it doesn't mean that my initial phone traffic (from other activities) will be considered under the vpn too? I think it will be 100% unrelated to vpn traffic, but i have no enough knowledges here to say for sure. Can someone clarify it?

Comment: Your setup is kind of vague, might be worth reading about TCP/IP routing tables.  There's a lot of control available but some VPN clients deliberately hide some of the options to try and make common tasks easier

Comment: it's not about real setup, it's more to get understanding how vpn in general works. I feel like it should be easier, effectively my question can be simplified to: There are 2 machines A and B, A shares WiFi for B, B connects to VPN,  can B's VPN make any effect on A? Ie if A is doing anything in internet, can it be considered as under VPN?

Comment: By default A would only see the encrypted traffic passing through it to the VPN provider.  You could set up rules so that A passed traffic back through the VPN on B but it would require careful configuration.  If the VPN was running on A then traffic from B might also be routed through the VPN as that's a more common use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a common and probably stupid question regarding vpn behaviour, but still it would be good to confirm my understanding. If i share internet from let's say my mobile phone (via Wi-Fi hotspot) and some other machine uses it (as Wi-Fi network) and then, this machine establishes vpn to some other network, it doesn't mean that my initial phone traffic (from other activities) will be considered under the vpn too?

No, they won't. VPN software does not actually "change your IP" or otherwise alter the way your Internet connection works overall.

It only creates a *new* virtual connection (tunnel) on top of it – the *VPN client app* redirects the user's traffic through the tunnel before it even leaves the device, at which point it becomes ordinary IP traffic addressed to the VPN server (carrying the original traffic inside).

Traffic that originates outside the VPN client's boundary isn't affected by this.